# How to change Netlify CMS for Strapi CMS?

Tags: frontend, content-management-system, gatsby, netlify, strapi

I'm new to this frontend world, I have some knowledge on React and GraphQL and that's why I've decided to try and implement a test blog with **Gatsby**, as it seems pretty popular and easy to use.

I also wanted to get my hands into Material UI so I'm using this Gatsby starter : https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/Vagr9K/gatsby-material-starter

This starter seems to have included the integration with **Netlify CMS**, so I wanted to change that and start using **Strapi CMS**, so I can have the content there.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of stuff in your question, I'll try to answer it step by step if not, please let me know if you need more details of how to create pages, etc and I will update my answer to add more details if needed.

If you want to change your source from Netlify to [Strapi](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-strapi/?=strapi) you need to set it up in your `gatsby-config.js`, replacing `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms` plugin for something like that:

```
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
    options: {
      apiURL: `http://localhost:1337`,
      queryLimit: 1000, // Default to 100
      contentTypes: [`article`, `user`],
      //If using single types place them in this array.
      singleTypes: [`home-page`, `contact`],
      // Possibility to login with a strapi user, when content types are not publically available (optional).
      loginData: {
        identifier: "",
        password: "",
      },
    },
  },
```

*Note that you'll have to install your desired plugins and remove the unnecessary in order to reduce the bundle package and improve performance when using starters.*

The next step is to create pages from your source CMS (articles, posts, pages, etc) using GraphQL. Maybe this blog [helps you](https://strapi.io/blog/strapi-starter-gatsby-blog). But as a short summary, you need to create queries in your `gatsby-node.js` to retrieve data from Strapi CMS and create pages using Gatsby's API.

The idea is the same as from your starters, however, instead of using gatsby-source-filesystem and using allMarkdownRemark in your page creation, you will use the object provided by Strapi CMS. You can check the queries and the available objects using gatsby develop and entering to [localhost:8000/___graphql](http://localhost:8000/___graphql).

Keep in mind that you will always query static data (i.e: pre-downloaded data) from your multiple sources so when you run the develop command, the data is downloaded and accessible via GraphQL.

You can check for further information in its [starter repository](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-starter-gatsby-blog/blob/master/frontend/gatsby-config.js).

Comment: One doubt that I'm having, now the content is represented as markdown pages with some styling taken from the templates folder, where should I make the query calls so it takes the information from strapi instead of the markdown pages?

Comment: The idea es the same, instead of using `gatsby-source-filesystem` and using `allMarkdownRemark` in your page creation, you will use the object provided by Strapi CMS. You can check the queries and the available objects using `gatsby develop` and entering to http://localhost:8000/___graphql. Keep in mind that you will always query static (i.e: pre-downloaded data) from your multiple sources so when you run the command, the data is downloaded and accessible via GraphQL.